# TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable on bytes stream

Tags: python, json

I have the following code excerpt:

```
my_response = my_func(
    plaintext='my data'.encode()))
    )
```

This throws a TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable exception, also, if I change this to:

```
my_response = my_func(
        json.dumps(dict(plaintext='my data'.encode()))
        )
```

I get:

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Can someone please advice as to how I can fix this, I'm using Python 3 BTW

Also, the argument I pass into my_func needs to be base64 encoded, but in text form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get the following code to do what I wanted:

```
dataStr = b'some data'
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(dataStr)
base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')

my_response = my_func( plaintext=base64_message )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is plainly calling the `.encode()` method. This returns a byte string, which you should not force JSON serialize. So, you need to use the `decode` method to "undo" or "reverse" this. Try this:

```
my_response = my_func(
    plaintext='my data'.encode().decode()))
)
```

Hope this answers your problem and helps you.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned that standard encode()/decode() will not work for me because I need to use base64 encoding/decoding